# Cloudinary uploading data from Typescript NodeJS server

Tags: node.js, typescript, cloudinary

I'm trying to upload images and videos from my server to Cloudinary but I'm facing lot of issues,
the files in request payload doesn't have a pathname.
Also streamifier doesn't have type declaration so cannot utilise it as well.

For reference,
This is the structure files from payload.

```
{
    fieldname: 'media',
    originalname: 'Screenshot 2021-03-25 at 1.42.05 AM.png',
    encoding: '7bit',
    mimetype: 'image/png',
    buffer: <Buffer 89 50 4e 47 0d 0a 1a 0a 00 00 00 0d 49 48 44 52 00 00 03 6c 00 00 00 ba 08 06 00 00 00 d2 e3 ce fe 00 00 0c 62 69 43 43 50 49 43 43 20 50 72 6f 66 69 ... 74947 more bytes>,
    size: 74997
  }
```

Comment: Can you explain more about the problem you're encountering? That payload doesn't look like Cloudinary's response format to their upload API - is that produced by another piece of middleware? If so, what's the problem with that payload

Comment: @Igy that isn't cloudinary response, this is the file object I'm receiving from res.files (multer middleware)

Comment: how did you set up cloudinary in typescript-node.js

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question so according to Cloudinary NodeJS docs, they suggest using streamifier library (https://www.npmjs.com/package/streamifier) , but this library doesn't have declaration library (@types) so I changed the strict property of tsconfig.json to false.

Reference:

- https://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360007581379-Correct-way-of-uploading-from-buffer-

It not correct way but for now it works.

Comment: If you know the correct types then you can also consider [contributing to definatelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped#how-can-i-contribute)